# Youtube api for .Net 2 framework

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to create a C# solution which should upload a video to youtube but I am limited to use .Net 2 framework because afterwords I will add the .dll file to Unity which doesn't support >2 .Net framework.

Answer (score 1):

You can't as of now. YouTube Data API requires **.NET 4.0 and above** while Unity's Mono environment only supports up to **.NET 3.5** (as of 5.5.1).

As long as Unity don't update .NET support, you are basically stuck with indirect access to the API only.

Comment: **Update** Now that the new Unity 2017.1+ version has introduced [experimental C#6 & .NET 4.6 support](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2017/07/11/introducing-unity-2017/), you should be good to go with the native YouTube Data API!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation for the youtube API for .NET you can port it yourself into .NET 2.0 by dragging the source into Unity and rewrite the functioality that is specific to .NET 2+

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet